# Cases with long math equation

Tags: math-mode, align, cases

What would be the best formatting of the following `align` and `cases` where the middle case has a very long math equation?

```
\begin{align*}
      V_{ijk}& = \begin{cases}
          \dfrac{y_u+y_l}2 - \dfrac{x_u+x_l}2,& \text{if }x_u < y_l\\[15pt]
          \dfrac1C \bigg[\dfrac{x_u^3-y_l^3}{6}+\dfrac{y_l^2+x_u^2}{2}x_l + (x_u-y_l)\dfrac{x_l^2}{2}+ \dfrac{y_u^2-x_u^2}{2}(x_u-x_l)& - (y_u-x_u)\dfrac{x_u^2-x_l^2}{2} \bigg],
          \\[12pt]& \text{if }x_u\in\left[y_l,y_u\right]\\[15pt]
          \dfrac1{x_u-x_l}\bigg[\dfrac{(y_u+y_l)^2}6 - \dfrac{y_u+y_l}2 x_l + \dfrac{x_l^2}2\bigg],& \text{otherwise}
      \end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

The main default of this current workaround which is nearly ok, is that there is an extra space before `-(y_u-x_u)` that is annoying. Note that I put the second if text under second equation because it would be too width for my memoir otherwise. Please favour simpliest solutions if possible :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with `\mfrac` from `nccmath` and `multlined` from the `mathtools` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\[
V_{ijk} = \begin{cases} 
  \mfrac{y_u+y_l}{2} - \mfrac{x_u+x_l}{2},  &\text{if }x_u < y_l    \\[3ex]
    \begin{multlined} 
    \mfrac{1}{C} \bigg[\mfrac{x_u^3-y_l^3}{6}+\mfrac{y_l^2+x_u^2}{2}x_l
      + (x_u-y_l)\mfrac{x_l^2}{2}\\[-2ex]
      + \mfrac{y_u^2-x_u^2}{2}(x_u-x_l) - (y_u-x_u)\mfrac{x_u^2-x_l^2}{2} \biggr]
    \end{multlined},
    & \text{if }x_u\in [y_l,y_u ]
    \\[5ex]
    \mfrac{1}{x_u-x_l}\biggl[\mfrac{(y_u+y_l)^2}{6} - \mfrac{y_u+y_l}{2} x_l
    + \mfrac{x_l^2}{2}\biggr],& \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow impressive! With `x_u\in\left[y_l,y_u\right]` that is above what I expected

Comment: Upvote for to share `\mfrac` and `\multlined`, as these are new to me....

Comment: @JKHA, oh this automatic replacement of `left[` with `\biggl[` ... corrected now

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it is a duplicate. But it is also easy to solve using `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  V_{ijk}& = \begin{cases} \dfrac{y_u+y_l}2 - \dfrac{x_u+x_l}2,&
    \text{if }x_u < y_l
    \\[15pt]
    \begin{aligned}[b]
      &\dfrac1C \bigg[\dfrac{x_u^3-y_l^3}{6}+\dfrac{y_l^2+x_u^2}{2}x_l
      + (x_u-y_l)\dfrac{x_l^2}{2}
      \\
      &+ \dfrac{y_u^2-x_u^2}{2}(x_u-x_l) -
      (y_u-x_u)\dfrac{x_u^2-x_l^2}{2} \bigg]
    \end{aligned},
    & \text{if }x_u\in\left[y_l,y_u\right]
    \\[15pt]
    \dfrac1{x_u-x_l}\bigg[\dfrac{(y_u+y_l)^2}6 - \dfrac{y_u+y_l}2 x_l
    + \dfrac{x_l^2}2\bigg],& \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought it would be less readable wrapping my second equation, but probably I was wrong

Comment: @JKHA it is pretty standard and it does fint on the paper. BTW: next time please provide a full minimal example including document class and minimal preamble like I do above. It makes it a lot faster for others to help you.

Comment: All right, I'll do it!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs a `dcases*` environment instead of the `cases` environment. The `d` in `dcases` denotes "display style"; this means, among other things, that one can write `\frac` instead of `\dfrac` in order to get "large" fraction terms.

[image]

Note that I've removed unnecessary `\left` and `\right` directives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases*' environment

\begin{document}
\[
V_{ijk} = 
\begin{dcases*} 
\frac{y_u+y_l}{2} - \frac{x_u+x_l}{2}\,,
   &if $x_u < y_l$\\[1ex]
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\frac{1}{C} \biggl[
   \frac{x_u^3-y_l^3}{6}+\frac{y_l^2+x_u^2}{2}x_l
   + (x_u-y_l)\frac{x_l^2}{2}\\
&\quad + \frac{y_u^2-x_u^2}{2}(x_u-x_l) 
   - (y_u-x_u)\frac{x_u^2-x_l^2}{2} \,\biggr]\,,
\end{aligned}
   &if $x_u\in[y_l,y_u]$ \\[1ex]
\frac{1}{x_u-x_l} \biggl[ 
   \frac{(y_u+y_l)^2}{6} 
   - \frac{y_u+y_l}{2} x_l 
   + \frac{x_l^2}{2} \,\biggr]\,,
   & otherwise
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is not to use `cases`, because it increases the interline spaces also inside nested alignments.

Using `multlined` for the long middle equation does the job.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
V_{ijk} = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \dfrac{y_u+y_l}2 - \dfrac{x_u+x_l}2, && \text{if }x_u < y_l
\\[2ex]
& \begin{multlined}[b]
    \dfrac{1}{C} \biggl[
      \dfrac{x_u^3-y_l^3}{6}+\dfrac{y_l^2+x_u^2}{2}x_l + (x_u-y_l)\dfrac{x_l^2}{2} \\
      + \dfrac{y_u^2-x_u^2}{2}(x_u-x_l) - (y_u-x_u)\dfrac{x_u^2-x_l^2}{2}
    \biggr],
  \end{multlined} && \text{if }x_u\in [y_l,y_u]
\\[2ex]
& \dfrac{1}{x_u-x_l}\biggl[
    \dfrac{(y_u+y_l)^2}6 - \dfrac{y_u+y_l}2 x_l + \dfrac{x_l^2}2
  \biggr], && \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid code such as `\frac1C` that's hard to read and to maintain. Also note `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of the unqualified `\bigg`.

Also avoid `align` for single equations (which this is an example of).

Comment: "because it increases the interline spaces also inside nested alignments". Sure? Yesterday's conversation was quite about this point: `aligned` does not care about being inside `cases`. Am I misunderstanding the statement?

Comment: @campa Uhm, that's quite bizarre indeed, but I guess `multlined` is affected.

Comment: Ah, good point, I missed that you were using `multlined`.