# Compress cases environment horizontally

Tags: cases

I currently have the following cases environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\[
G(x,u) = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi + x - u)}{4\sinh \pi} & \text{for \(0 \le x \le u \le \pi\)}\vspace{0.25em}\\
-\dfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi - x + u)}{4\sinh \pi} & \text{\phantom{for} \(0 \le u \le x \le \pi\).}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

but it produces a result that sticks out into the margin:

[image: current LaTeX output]

I think the natural way to fix this would be to intersperse the expressions and conditions in the following way (apologies for bad image editing, but hopefully it's clear what I mean):

[image: desired LaTeX output]

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this with cases or similar?

---

This is similar to the desired output in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504188/cases-with-long-math-equation?rq=1), which used a hack to produce something along the right lines. But the answers in that case focused on splitting the expressions, which doesn't work well for me.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to a MWE.

Comment: Please tell us how wide the textblock is and which font size you employ (10pt?, 11pt?, 12pt?, someething else?).

Comment: @Zarko Done (based on your example below – thanks).

Comment: @Mico 10pt, A4 paper and default margins for article class. The important thing is that the expressions fit into the column on their own, but the conditions don't fit next to them.

Comment: Meanwhile you receive two answers ... are non of them is not worth to be upvoted or even the best one (for your expectation) to be accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the condition to a new line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
G(x,u) = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{\cosh(\pi-x-u)+\cosh(\pi+x+u)-2\cosh(\pi+x-u)}{4\sinh\pi} & \\
                     & \makebox[0pt][r]{for $0 \le x \le u \le\pi$} \\[2ex]
-\dfrac{\cosh(\pi-x-u)+\cosh(\pi+x+u)-2\cosh(\pi-x+u)}{4\sinh\pi} & \\
                     & \makebox[0pt][r]{$0\le u\le x\le\pi$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Since there is a lengthy common expression, you could do the following:

[image]

```
In the following definition, let $C=\cosh(\pi-x-u)+\cosh(\pi+x+u).$
\[
G(x,u) = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{C - 2\cosh (\pi + x - u)}{4\sinh \pi} & \text{for \(0 \le x \le u \le \pi\)}\vspace{0.25em}\\
-\dfrac{C - 2\cosh (\pi - x + u)}{4\sinh \pi} & \text{\phantom{for} \(0 \le u \le x \le \pi\).}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why this is not a useful answer?

Answer (score 5):

I propose this variant layout, based on the `fleqn`  environment and the mediumsized fractions from `nccmath`:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[66]
    \begin{fleqn}
    \[
    \begin{aligned}
     & G(x,u)= \\
     & \begin{cases}\begin{alignedat}{2}
     & -\mfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi + x - u)}{4\sinh \pi} &\qquad \text{for } & 0 \le x \le u \le \pi, \\[2ex]
     & -\mfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi - x + u)}{4\sinh \pi} & & 0 \le u \le x \le \pi.
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
    \]
    \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is use of the `\splitfrac{` defined in the `mathtools` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
G(x,u) = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{\splitfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u)}
                  {- 2\cosh (\pi + x - u)}}
       {4\sinh \pi}     & \text{for \(0 \le x \le u \le \pi\)}\vspace{0.25em}\\[3ex]
-\dfrac{\splitfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u)} 
                  {- 2\cosh (\pi - x + u)}}
       {4\sinh \pi}     & \text{\phantom{for} \(0 \le u \le x \le \pi\).}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, if you define`\textwidth` with `geometry package, for example, as is done in the next MWE, that your equation nice fit on page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
G(x,u) = \begin{cases}
-\dfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi + x - u)}
       {4\sinh \pi}     & \text{for \(0 \le x \le u \le \pi\)}\vspace{0.25em}\\[3ex]
-\dfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi - x + u)}
       {4\sinh \pi}     & \text{\phantom{for} \(0 \le u \le x \le \pi\).}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, please consider my comment below your question!

Answer (score 4):

I endorse your idea, with a few fixes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
G(x,u) = \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    -\dfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi + x - u)}{4\sinh \pi}
    \qquad
    \\[-1ex]
    \text{for \(0 \le x \le u \le \pi\),}
    \\[2ex]
    -\dfrac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi - x + u)}{4\sinh \pi}
    \qquad
    \\[-1ex]
    \text{for \(0 \le u \le x \le \pi\).}
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can do it without cases:

```
\[
G(x,u)=
  -\frac{\cosh (\pi - x - u) + \cosh(\pi + x + u) - 2\cosh (\pi - \lvert x - u\rvert)}
        {4\sinh \pi}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the best option so far. The form using $\lvert x-u \rvert$ is actually the previous step in the calculation, but by considering the two cases $x<u$ and $x>u$ it's possible to simplify slightly further. (These are lecture notes for second-year undergraduates, so I'm showing some detail of the algebra.)

Comment: @StephenPowell In that case I'd avoid the cases: first you analyze what happen for *u* ≤ *x* and then for *x* ≤ *u*.